# What purpose does the 'Assembly' in this code have?

Tags: c#, .net

```
foreach (Type i in typeof(Packet).Assembly.GetTypes())
{
    if (typeof(Packet).IsAssignableFrom(i) && !i.IsAbstract)
    {
        Packet Packet = (Packet)Activator.CreateInstance(i);
        if (!(Packet is ServerPacket))
        {
            if (!Packets.ContainsKey(Packet.PacketID))
            {
                Packets.Add(Packet.PacketID, Packet);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From what I understand, this code does a for-each function where the `i` is a `Packet` class, then I don't understand the code `typeof(Packet).IsAssignableFrom(i)` and `(Packet)Activator.CreateInstance(i)`

Could someone explain these functions to me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Okay, we now know which parts you don't understand - did you look at the documentation of `Type.IsAssignableFrom` and `Activator.CreateInstance`? If so, which parts of that documentation are unclear to you?

Comment: No `i` is not `Packet` (although it can be). `i` is any type retrieved from assembly in which `Pocket` resides. But if `Packet` derived from that type - code will continue. `Activator` is simply object that can make instance of the class from its declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly; if we break this down:

```
foreach (Type i in typeof(Packet).Assembly.GetTypes())
```

Starting with:

```
                   typeof(Packet)
```

This [returns a `Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/typeof) object, representing various metadata about the type `Packet`.

```
                   typeof(Packet).Assembly
```

This [returns the assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.assembly?view=netframework-4.7.2) which contains the `Packet` type/class.  "Assembly" here is roughly synonymous with DLL, although it can include EXE files (and others).  In a Visual Studio context, if you have multiple projects, each project is typically compiled into a separate assembly.

```
                   typeof(Packet).Assembly.GetTypes()
```

This [returns all the types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes?view=netframework-4.7.2) defined in the assembly we just referenced.

We can now see that your original...

```
foreach (Type i in typeof(Packet).Assembly.GetTypes())
```

...will iterate through all the types defined in the assembly that contains the `Packet` type.